# Unzipping throws an "The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly"

Tags: c#, .net, zip, compression, uwp

Trying to unzip a file on Win10 mobile (UWP) with the following code

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
  ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.Entries.First();
  using (Stream reader = entry.Open())
  {
```

throws at entry.Open() the following error.
"The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly."

with the inner exception

"Unable to load DLL 'clrcompression.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Important to note:

- The entry.Open() works fine on win10 Desktop but not on Win10 mobile with the same project (UWP)
- Using Win10 mobile version 10.0.14393.576. (Lumia 650)
- UWP target version of the project is 10.0 BUILD 14393
- Using the same file for the Desktop and mobile version.
- The file is created at the backend with a simple

`using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create,true))`

- I am using Xamarin forms (I don't think this is relevant)

Questions: 
Has somebody experienced the same exception? What is the root cause of it?
What are available workarounds? (I need the file compressed cross platform)

UPDATE: I created  simple test project as requested (thanks for looking into it).

The unzip works in the test project, but it is loading a different module.
The Debug/Modules window states that the exception throwing project uses System.IO.Compression.dll 4.06.24705.1, the working project uses 1.00.24301.1.

I uploaded both project.lock.json files for comparison https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqROiejT4oI3lL1q1tu3iJcfA2tKyg.

Comment: For me it's like the `zip` library that you are using haves some dependencies that are present in the desktop version on Windows 10, and those dependencies are not present in the mobile version

Comment: Yes, I think that too, but what should an honest .NETer use, if not the ZipArchive api? (Which is a part of .NET)

Comment: I've always use the DotNetZip library: https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

Comment: looking at the GitHub and nuget it looks like it has no dependencies preventing it for cross plat. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in my side. I'm testing with Lumia 640 with the same OS version as yours. Have you tried with a UWP project not Xamarin Forms? If you still has the problem, could you please share a [mcve] so that we can reproduce you issue?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT thanks for the help, I updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the "project.lock.json" you've uploaded, I think the problem here may be related to the [System.IO.Compression 4.3.0 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression/).

In the exception throwing project, you can find it uses "System.IO.Compression 4.3.0" like following:

```
"runtime.native.System.IO.Compression/4.3.0": {
  "type": "package",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Targets": "1.1.0"
  },
  "compile": {
    "lib/netstandard1.0/_._": {}
  },
  "runtime": {
    "lib/netstandard1.0/_._": {}
  }
},
...
"System.IO.Compression/4.3.0": {
  "type": "package",
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Buffers": "4.3.0",
    "System.Collections": "4.3.0",
    "System.Diagnostics.Debug": "4.3.0",
    "System.IO": "4.3.0",
    "System.Resources.ResourceManager": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime.Handles": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.3.0",
    "System.Text.Encoding": "4.3.0",
    "System.Threading": "4.3.0",
    "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.3.0",
    "runtime.native.System.IO.Compression": "4.3.0"
  },
  ...
```

And in the working project, it uses "System.IO.Compression 4.1.1":

```
"runtime.native.System.IO.Compression/4.1.0": {
  "type": "package",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Targets": "1.0.1"
  },
  "compile": {
    "lib/netstandard1.0/_._": {}
  },
  "runtime": {
    "lib/netstandard1.0/_._": {}
  }
},
...
"System.IO.Compression/4.1.1": {
  "type": "package",
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11",
    "System.Diagnostics.Debug": "4.0.11",
    "System.IO": "4.1.0",
    "System.Resources.ResourceManager": "4.0.1",
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.Handles": "4.0.1",
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.1.0",
    "System.Text.Encoding": "4.0.11",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11",
    "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.11",
    "runtime.native.System.IO.Compression": "4.1.0"
  },
  ...
```

It seems that [System.IO.Compression 4.3.0 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression/) can't be used in UWP project for now. Currently the latest stable version of "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" package uses "System.IO.Compression 4.1.1" package. And you should be able to reproduce your issue with the working project by adding [System.IO.Compression 4.3.0 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression/) in it like following:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
    "System.IO.Compression": "4.3.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": { }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": { },
    "win10-arm-aot": { },
    "win10-x86": { },
    "win10-x86-aot": { },
    "win10-x64": { },
    "win10-x64-aot": { }
  }
}
```

So to fix this issue, I'd suggest you check the reference of your project and make sure there is no "System.IO.Compression 4.3.0" package. If you do need to use "System.IO.Compression" package, you can try to downgrade it to "4.1.1".

Answer (score 3):

I found the root cause. As Jay Zuo said, the problem is that in the project.lock.json is somehow referencing the "System.IO.Compression 4.3.0".

I am not directly referencing it in any project.json file. I am indirectly referencing it by a .NETSTANDARD1.1 project with a reference to the "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1".

By using nuget.org I searched for a "NETStandard.Library" version using the older System.IO.Compression 4.1.1, which is "NETStandard.Library" 1.6.0.

Using the "NETStandard.Library" 1.6.0. in the .NETSTANDARD 1.1 project fixed the unzip error.

I uploaded a sample solution to reproduce the error. https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqROiejT4oI3lMMc_jWogCQy36awrA

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, but I don't see anywhere a reference to Net standard library in the list of references (maybe another reference is indirectly referencing it like you said).  But which one?  Can I install the older version manually using nuget package manager? I tried that but still same result, how do I get it to load the older version?

Comment: have you searched for "System.IO.Compression" in all lock.json files in all your projects? I don't know which dll it will use during runtime if you have referenced both, but i think it failed on my project.

Answer (score 3):

Fix for me was to add this to the first `PropertyGroup` in the .csproj file:

```
<NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
```

Visual Studio normally implicitly pulls in 1.6.1 for .NET Standard projects, which has the problematic System.IO.Compression 4.3.0. The directive tells it to pull down 1.6.0 instead, which depends on System.IO.Compression 4.1.1 (which works on Windows Phone).

Just make sure you don't have another NuGet reference which is pulling in 4.3.0. The correct file version for System.IO.Compression.dll is 1.0.24301.1 and the broken one is 4.6.xxxx .