# The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I can no longer use System.IO.Compression library in my UWP app, I need it to compress a string which is too large uncompressed to fit in isolated storage.  I'm suspicious this started when I updated all my Nuget packages. I keep getting the following error, code follows below it,

**EDIT** This appears to be happening in DEBUG mode only.  When I compile my app in RELEASE mode and deploy to device or local machine, it works on both.  But when I try to Debug, it crashes (crash happens in later code that tries to use the decompressed string which contains nothing because the compress/decompress failed silently - at the using statement - and the  remainder of the code in my app was executed)

Message

> The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly.

StackTrace

> at System.IO.Compression.Deflater.DeflateInit(CompressionLevel
>   compressionLevel, Int32 windowBits, Int32 memLevel,
>   CompressionStrategy strategy)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.Deflater..ctor(CompressionLevel
>   compressionLevel, Int32 windowBits)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InitializeDeflater(Stream stream,
>   Boolean leaveOpen, Int32 windowBits, CompressionLevel
>   compressionLevel)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor(Stream stream,
>   CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Int32 windowBits)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor(Stream stream,
>   CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)    at
>   myApp.Utilities.Extensions.Compress(String uncompressedString)    at
>   myApp.ExtendedSplash.d__17.MoveNext()

I think its something to do with this perhaps

[Unzipping throws an "The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185291/unzipping-throws-an-the-underlying-compression-routine-could-not-be-loaded-corr)

I don't know what to do.  Is there an alternative Zip library that does not rely on System.IO, I can use in UWP? - I tried to install DotNetZip but it will not install.

Code

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compresses a string and returns a deflate compressed, Base64 encoded string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uncompressedString">String to compress</param>
    public static string Compress(this string uncompressedString)
    {
        var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
        var uncompressedStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uncompressedString));

        using (var compressorStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            uncompressedStream.CopyTo(compressorStream);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(compressedStream.ToArray());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decompresses a deflate compressed, Base64 encoded string and returns an uncompressed string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="compressedString">String to decompress.</param>
    public static string Decompress(this string compressedString)
    {
        var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream();
        var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(compressedString));

        using (var decompressorStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decompressorStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code. But I could not reproduce your issue, and the version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatfom is 5.1.0 in my project. You could provide more detail about nuget package version you have referenced just like you mentioned in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the clrcompression.dll file is corrupted. Clean and build or rebuild the solution.