# GZipStream throws an exception:The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly

Tags: c#, compression

I am using the following method to compress files, but it throws an exception "**The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly**".

```
CompressFile(string sDir, string sRelativePath, GZipStream zipStream)
    {
        //Compress file name
        char[] chars = sRelativePath.ToCharArray();
        zipStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(chars.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
        foreach (char c in chars)
            zipStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(c), 0, sizeof(char));

        //Compress file content
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(sDir, sRelativePath));
        zipStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
        zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Is this on .Net-core?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185291/unzipping-throws-an-the-underlying-compression-routine-could-not-be-loaded-corr

Comment: It is on .Net Framework 3.5 @rene